# TransactionScope with Object context on dependant objects

Tags: entity-framework, oracle11g, transactionscope, objectcontext

I'm working on a MVC3 application and i'm using the Entity Framework linked to an Oracle database (11G R2).
I'm encountering an issue when i'm trying to use a single object context inside a `TransactionScope`.

Here is the code :

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (Entities context = new Entities())
    {
        // Right insert
        T_RIGRIGHT entity1 = new T_RIGRIGHT()
        {
            RIGCODE = "test1",
            RIGINSERTLOGIN = "aco",
            RIGINSERTDATE = DateTime.Now,
            RIGUPDATELOGIN = "aco",
            RIGUPDATEDATE = DateTime.Now
        };

        context.AddToT_RIGRIGHT(entity1);

        context.SaveChanges();

        // Right/Profile insert
        T_RIPRIGHTPROFILE entity2 = new T_RIPRIGHTPROFILE()
        {
            PROID = 3,
            RIGID = entity1.RIGID,
            RIPINSERTLOGIN = "aco",
            RIPINSERTDATE = DateTime.Now,
            RIPUPDATELOGIN = "aco",
            RIPUPDATEDATE = DateTime.Now
        };

        context.AddToT_RIPRIGHTPROFILE(entity2);

        context.SaveChanges(); // SaveChanges fails due to the FK constraint on table 
    }

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Let me explain the code...

First I create an entity called `entity1` as a `T_RIGRIGHT` element.
The I instanciate a `T_RIPRIGHTPROFILE` element that uses the id of the T_RIGRIGHT element created before.

The execution fails on the second `context.SaveChanges()` and the exception concerns the Foreign Key constraint on the table `T_RIPRIGHTPROFILE` (requires a `T_RIGRIGHT`).

Hope my explanations are clear enough

Is there any way to make it works ?

P.S. : I apologize for my english as it's not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign the FK `entity1.RIGID` of an entity that has not been committed to the DB:

```
RIGID = entity1.RIGID,
```

If you look at entity1 closely you will see that  `RIGID` is 0 by default - instead you should set the navigation property representing the FK relationship:

```
RIG = entity1,
```

This will enable EF to properly relate these entities, for this entity1 does not have to be committed to the DB yet, so you do not even need the extra `SaveChanges()` call.

Also in your scenario you do not need a `TransactionScope` - EF uses a transaction internally already in `SaveChanges()` - based on the suggested changes you only need one `SaveChanges()` call and hence no outer transaction scope is needed.